# Email drip campaigns through CiviRules or Chasse?

Tags: civimail, email

Edited: specifying our goals.

I'd like to know the process of setting up email "drip" campaigns or marketing series through CiviRules and Chasse.

Could someone explain how each one works? What are the benefits of one over the other?

We'd like to set up three email series:

- A welcome series for non-members with a series of messages asking folks to donate memberships (and ending the campaign if they do buy a membership)
  _ A welcome series for members thanking them and telling them where their investment will go
- A re-engagement series for people who haven't opened an email in more than a year

Comment: It may help folk answer if you explain what your goal / workflow will be

Comment: I don't know Chasse but by sounds of your workflow/logic I can envisage this working with CiviRules +/- Scheduled Reminders (ie you can do the 'series for members' purely as Sch.Rems perhaps

Answer (score 1):

We currently use Chasse.

Pros:

- Really great UI.
- Setting up DRIP campaigns is clear
- Integration with Mosaico is good
- We can see where a person is in a DRIP campaign from their contact record
- We can see where a campaign is in its flow through the UI

Cons:

- Only one, but it's major...an individual person can only be part of one campaign at a time.

This one con may cause us to stop using Chasse.

For example, if we have a new member and they get enrolled in the new member campaign, if they then enroll in a year-long class that itself has a DRIP email flow - bingo, that won't work with Chasse.

So.  If you are confident that your people will only need to be in one DRIP campaign at a time -- Chasse is fantastic.  As soon as that is not the case, Chasse unfortunately is no longer an option.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SE!

Chasse is intended for that purpose and is pretty well explained in its documentation [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/chasse/en/latest/).  Ask if there's something specific you don't understand but it's easy enough to install it and experiment.

CiviRules is a more general-purpose tool. It could be used for what you want but will take more setup effort.